# Obtener el valor de un input html en javascript

Tags: javascript, html, input

Estoy haciendo un ejercicio de obtener un numero al azar y que el usuario escriba un numero y si escribe el correcto que muestre en pantalla. El problema es que no puedo obtener el valor del Input en javascript. Intenté con el id, la class y nada, realmente no se que me estaría faltando. Mi código es el siguiente

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Números mágicos Lucas Lopez :DDDDDDD</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="play">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="playGame()">Comenzar Juego</button>    </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <span>Introduce un numero</span>
        <input type="text" class="num">
         <button onclick="IngresarNumero()">Enviar</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    
        <script src="./app.js"></script>
</body>
```

JavaScript:

```
   let numeroAleatorio = null
let numeroIntroducir = document.getElementById('.num');



function playGame(){
    console.log("Comenzó el juego!")
    alert("Se generó el número aleatorio!")
    numeroAleatorioBot();
}

function numeroAleatorioBot() {
    return numeroAleatorio = Math.round(Math.random()*10)
}

function IngresarNumero() {
    if (numeroIntroducir===numeroAleatorio) {
        alert("GANASTE")
    }else{
        alert("PERDISTE!")
    }
}
```

Comment: `document.getElementById('.num')` <-- tal como el nombre del método indica, necesitas pasar la Id del elemento al que quieras tener una referencia y en tu caso le estas pasando el nombre de la clase `.num`, como solo tienes un solo input en tu documento cambia en la etiqueta `<input>` el `class="num"` por `id="num"` y quita el punto de `.num` dentro del string pasado por `getElementById()`, con esto todo debería estar bien

Comment: Ya lo hice pero tampoco me estaría funcionando.. Creo que esta algo mal en la función  IngresarNumero()

Comment: Me debo disculpar, lo que mencione fue un error que note al ver el código de reojo pero no lo analice debidamente para ver si hay mas de un error, en un momento reviso.

Comment: Bien muchas gracias!

Comment: Listo, ya publico la respuesta.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aparte de los cambios que te dije en los comentarios sobre cambiar `class="num"` por `id="num"`, encontré otro error en la siguiente parte:

```
function IngresarNumero() {
    if (numeroIntroducir===numeroAleatorio) {
        alert("GANASTE")
    }else{
        alert("PERDISTE!")
    }
}
```

`numeroIntroducir` no es el valor que se coloque en el `<input>` si no es que es una referencia al propio `<input>` (si usas `console.log(numeroIntroducir)` veras que imprimirá toda la etiqueta), para obtener su valor debes usar la propiedad `value` de la siguiente forma: `numeroIntroducir.value` esta tendrá el valor que coloques, la otra cosa es que este valor del `<input>` siempre es un `string` y cuando haces `===` estas evaluando si ambos tienen el mismo tipo de dato (uno es un `string` y el otro un número), aquí tienes una corrección de esta parte:

```
function IngresarNumero() {
    if (numeroIntroducir.value == numeroAleatorio) {
        alert("GANASTE")
    }else{
        alert("PERDISTE!")
    }
}
```

link de referencias:
[Propiedad value de la etiqueta input](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_text_value.asp)

nota: También puedes usar el método [Element.getAttribute()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute) para obtener el valor del input~

Comment: Perfecto! Muchas gracias me sacaste las dudas te lo agradezco!

Comment: np man, cualquier otra duda acá estamos y si esto soluciono tu problema me seria fantástico si marcas la respuesta como correcta^^